How to calibrate display to non-sRGB color space?
I am not a photographer. I am an end user with a monitor (GIGABYTE M27U) capable of displaying wider-than-sRGB color gamut.
The sRGB mode on the monitor is pre-calibrated and looks pretty good, but obviously doesn't extend into the wider color gamut.
I would like to calibrate one of my monitor's non-sRGB modes to Display-P3 (the Apple one with a 6500K whitepoint, not DCI-P3).
How would I do this using a colorimeter? I was considering buying the Calibrite Display 123

You don't. You calibrate the monitor so it displays it's RGB color space as accurately as possible. The program will then tell/show you how the monitor's color space compares to other RGB color spaces. I.e. 100% sRGB, 100% P3, 96% adobeRGB, etc. And it may also show the monitor's color space extending beyond the reference color space in areas.
I.e. it is somewhat incorrect to say a display is an sRGB monitor; it is an RGB display. It may also be an RGB display that is also capable of displaying the entire sRGB gamut, or P3, or anything else.
This shows my monitor's color space as currently calibrated (red) in comparison to sRGB (black) as 99% because it is missing a small area lower left; even though it's gamut is larger in all other areas.

And this shows it as being 89% of P3.


Ahh I see. So when a colorimeter runs, what exactly is it calibrating against?

@PrithviBoinpally, visible light/color as described by RGB notation... the large area of color the triangles fall within.

So what would it mean to say a monitor is "off" or improperly calibrated? And does calibration only involve RGB? What about things like white point and gamma?

When a monitor is "off" it displays a color different from what it is told to display; that includes white point (white balance) and gamma (brightness). E.g. it displays 255/245/255 when told to display 255/255/255. But even when maximally calibrated, it can only accurately display the colors it is capable of (that are within it's own color space/gamut).

Thanks so much for the explanation!

Essentially, every device has it's own primaries (shades of R,G,B), that means it cannot be calibrated to a color space only to be similar, usually this just means matching the brightness curve (like a gamma or sRGB's). You profile the display so a color-aware app knows the colors it really produces and can convert more precisely by adjusting color numbers.
